# Creating A Standalone Python exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

New to programming. I created a python program and wanted to make it standalone using cx_Freeze. I've installed a whp. file from their website and I had problems installing cx_Freeze, as when I try to do a pip, install: it says "pip is not recognized.

When running my setup.py it says error importing cx_Freeze as such module doesn't exist.

Comment: If you're on Windows, chances are high `pip.exe` is not on your standard path. You'll have to run it from its installation directory. E.g. instead of `pip`, rather run `C:\Python\bin\pip.exe` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
pyinstaller yourfile.py -F --onefile
```

This creates a standalone EXE file on Windows.

Important note 1: The EXE file will be generated in a folder named 'dist'.

Important note 2: Do not forget --onefile flag

You can install PyInstaller using pip install PyInstaller

NOTE: In rare cases there are hidden dependencies...so if you run the EXE file and get missing library error (win32timezone in the example below) then use something like this:

```
pyinstaller --hiddenimport win32timezone -F "Backup Program.py"
```